# Google App Engine does not find pip package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I am deployging a python app in Google App Engine and I am facing an error when running `google cloud deploy`

My requiremetns.txt file includes the followign python packages and versions:

```
requests==2.31.0
ipyleaflet==0.18.0
ipywidgets==8.1.1
ipyfilechooser
jupyterlab==4.0.9
shapely==2.0.2
voila==0.5.5
mercantile==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
geojson==3.1.0
geopandas==0.14.1
rasterio==1.3.9
ipydatagrid==1.2.0
```

The Google shell is prompting this error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.31.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.6.4, 0.6.5, 0.6.6, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.4, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 0.8.4, 0.8.5, 0.8.6, 0.8.7, 0.8.8, 0.8.9, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.10.4, 0.10.6, 0.10.7, 0.10.8, 0.11.1, 0.11.2, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5, 0.13.6, 0.13.7, 0.13.8, 0.13.9, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.14.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.10.0, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.12.2, 2.12.3, 2.12.4, 2.12.5, 2.13.0, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.14.2, 2.15.1, 2.16.0, 2.16.1, 2.16.2, 2.16.3, 2.16.4, 2.16.5, 2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.17.2, 2.17.3, 2.18.0, 2.18.1, 2.18.2, 2.18.3, 2.18.4, 2.19.0, 2.19.1, 2.20.0, 2.20.1, 2.21.0, 2.22.0, 2.23.0, 2.24.0, 2.25.0, 2.25.1, 2.26.0, 2.27.0, 2.27.1)
Step #2: ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==2.31.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
Step #2: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
Step #2: You should consider upgrading via the '/env/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Step #2: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #2
ERROR
```

I wonder why the latest version of requests is not seen as an option? I have put 2.27.1 and then the same error takes place for the next package. Why is that? How can I fix it?

ps: I am rather new with App Engine

--- EDIT --

My app.yaml file looks like this, specifying python to version 3

```
runtime: python
env: flex
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
entrypoint: voila --port=$PORT --Voila.ip=0.0.0.0 --no-browser main.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an older version of Python.  Requests 2.27.1 was the last version that supports Python 2.7 or Python 3.6.

Change your app.yaml to have this:

```
runtime_config:
  runtime_version: "3.12"
```

This will use Python 3.12.  You could use any of 3.7 to 3.12 but might as well use the latest version.

Comment: I have edited my quesiton, showing how I have my app.yaml file set. It points to python 3

Comment: @GCGM, I updated my answer to address the additional info in your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Requests 2.31.0 requires a minimum of Python 3.7 (see [docs](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.31.0/))

   > Requires: Python >=3.7
2. If your app.yaml setting just says Python 3, App engine will use  Python 3.6.10 (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#previous_runtime_versions)).
3. From the above you have a mismatch. You need to update your app.yaml setting and specify a specific version of Python 3.7. <s>If you want to use something higher, then you have to use a custom runtime (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#other_python_runtime_support))</s>

**Update:**

a) Struck out last sentence in the last bullet point based on feedback from @minou

b) To use higher versions of Python, see [this part](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime#newversions) of the documentation

Comment: You don't need a custom runtime.  I'm running 3.11 on both standard and flex GAE apps.  The page you linked to is confusing but there is an example there with Python 3.12.

Comment: @minou - I've updated my response based on your feedback